# Testing web service connectivity with CXF

Tags: java, web-services, connection, cxf

I have a CXF web service that I use through a Swing client. First, I create a `JaxWsProxyFactoryBean`, then I create the JAX WS proxy. At this point, I want to test that the client can properly send a message to the web service. I understand that HTTP is a stateless protocol thus it does not use any connection at its layer. Until now, I've used a ping() method defined by the web service in order for the client to test connectivity.

What is the proper way to do that? I don't think adding a dummy method to the API just to allow testing connectivity is the best solution. Is there a CXF way to do that though the proxy?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of options to do so:

1. I assume that your web service is SOAP web service, then you can issue a HTTP HEAD request for the WSDL document.
2. Implement a special "ping" operation (SOAP) in the web service. (Probably you already have it)

If you choose first option - make a HTTP HEAD request you can use following code to achieve that:

```
public static boolean exists(String webServiceUrl){
    try {
        HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(webServiceUrl).openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
        return connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK;
    } catch (Exception e) {      
        return false;
    }
}
```

If you are to perform HEAD request to your web service, this means that web service is accessible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I said in the question, until now I used a special ping operation. I like the first solution you proposed but I wonder if not using the CXF proxy to issue the HEAD request may be an issue. Issuing a HEAD request using a HttpURLConnection will only check that there is connectivity with the service. But, I also want to check I can access the service through the CXF proxy since it will be the one that will be used by the client to access the service. Do you know if it is possible to issue the HEAD request through the CXF proxy?