# Test CXF Connections

Tags: java, cxf

About testing web service connectivity in general, there's a great answer to [this question about testing web services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14237799/testing-web-service-connectivity-with-cxf).

However, there are cases where it can be rather a nuisance to create your own URL connections separately for the test. For example, when client certificates are involved.

So, is there some way to make a HEAD call to a web service configured with CXF just as a kind of heartbeat check?

I've looked at the source and found HTTPConduit, but connectionFactory is protected, createConnection is private, prepare method appears to be something but how to use it/how to get result... it's messy. ClientImpl.doInoke maybe but it creates the message inside it so not easy to change it and it has lots of parameters... I dug around and there's certainly nothing obvious I've found so far

Comment: Is it a REST or a SOAP service? Doing a heartbeat with REST is trivial.

Comment: @DonalFellows It's SOAP.

Comment: I'm always thankful in an integration project when the customer has provided an explicit NOP echo/ping operation in their interface that will verify authorization as well as connectivity.